# Plugins error in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, ftp

Im trying to install som plugins on my WordPress site but Im gettin the error message halfthrough the progress:
"Downloading install package from https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/responsive-lightbox.1.4.4.zip…

Unpacking the package…

Could not create directory."

The site is hosted as localhost and Im using phpMyAdmin as database if that's to any help.
The plugins map is inside the wp-content map. I have given access so it can be overwritten and edit by anyone. But it seems not to fix my problem.

Before I could upload I had some problem with FTP. WordPress kept asking me for FTP but I shut it off by adding

```
<?php   
define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');
?>
```

in the "functions.php" file. Don't know if that's critical to my problem, but just mention it to be on the safe side.

So, how do I solve this problem about plugins?

Thanks!

yours sincerely,
winterwind

Answer (score 0):

Put this line of code in your wp-config.php right below your database credentials, not in the functions.php.

If this problem still occur change the permissions in your wp-content folder (and subfolders to 777 (only on localhost) by doing this in your wordpress-folder:

```
chmod -R 777 wp-content
```

This is kinda dirty, but works fine on localhost.

Comment: Im getting error from dreamweaver.
Is it just pure "chmod -R 777 wp-content"?.
And right below database collate type?

Comment: The chmod method is a command in your shell/Terminal. Open your shell and go to your wordpress folder. In your wp-config.php will go the FS_METHOD.